# Telerik Winforms Reports freeze on Terminal Services

Tags: telerik, terminal-services

I am using Telerik reports in our app and it is being accessed mostly through an RDP session running in "app mode". Everything works fine locally but when I put it on the TS machine it freezes after the print dialog comes up.

The standard print dialog comes up and you can choose the printer and hit ok but then a small box opens with header of Printing... and then never does anything.

I am not sure what code to post since its fine locally, let me know what you want to see. also printing other things like the Telerik grids and charts are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on my own.

I created a standard printdialog screen and "rolled my own" print method and all seems to be good. Hope this helps someone else.

```
private void reportViewer1_Print(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            e.Cancel = true;

            try
            {
                PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
                pd.PrinterSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
                var result = pd.ShowDialog();
                if (result ==DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    // Print the report using the custom print controller
                    var reportProcessor
                        = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();

                    reportProcessor.PrintReport(this.reportViewer1.ReportSource, pd.PrinterSettings); 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program.ExceptionHandler(ex);
            }
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
```